# Grab value of array(key:array(key:val)) dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a calculation done that looks up values in my array of arrays with keys; what I am trying to accomplish is something like this.

Eg> If score value is 1 > go to array grab key 1 now there is second parameter which we can say total. Now we grab an array from the key 1 and from with in it we look for total `key -> value`.

It could look like this Score = 1 Total = 4 Value = ?

`array 1:[1:3,2:6,3:19,4:55];`

So result should return value 55.

```
var scores =[{1:[{value:'4'},{score:'1'},{css:'green'}]}];
```

To keep it simple i only used 1 key in outer array.

Also I used a loop to see how this plays out,

```
for (var key in scores){
    console.log(scores[key]);
    var arr = scores[key];
    for (var value in arr){
        console.log(arr[value]);
        var single = arr[value];
        for(var val in single){
            console.log(single[val]);
        }
    }
}
```

Final loops shows me the inner array with keys and values as Objects

Now I am wondering what would be the best and quickest way for me to get these values if I do something like

```
function getValue(Score, Total){
    alert("Key " + value + "is " + this); 
    alert("Key " + score + "is " + this); 
    alert("Key " + css + "is " + this); 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I agree with T.J. You almost seem to be confusing array structure `[]` with objects `{}`. Arrays don't have key properties, they only have indices. In this example `scores` is a array that contains one object, with a single property called `'1'`, whose value is an array of three objects, each having a property `value`, `score`, and `css`, respectively.

Comment: Yes there is many scores depending on the matrix user is on, it can have anywhere from 4 up to 6 scores. and each score has its own values. I guess simplest way to put it is a 4x4 up to  6x6 if you would write it on paper :).

Comment: `[1:3,2:6,3:19,4:55]` is an invalid structure. There is no such thing as an array with keys. You'll get this error:  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. You could just use something like this:

```
var scores = [
    {'value': 4, 'css': 'green'}, // This is key 0
    {'value': 9, 'css': 'yellow'} // This is key 1 etc
];

function getScoresValue( key, prop ) {
    return scores[key][prop];
}

// Example:

console.log(  getScoresValue(1, "css") ); // yellow
```

Comment: Would you rather use an object and get O(n) complexity?

Comment: His scores start at 1, that's why I started with index 1.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ya... any way trying to improve that one. Hope keewnn didn't mind my "*community driven*" edit.

Comment: The only thing that bothers me is that you changed the indent style from Allman to KNF

Comment: This works .. Thanks I was having hard time figuring out how to target it correctly.. this is right on the money thanks everyone!